# Wrap Multiple Azure Table Queries in One HTTP Shot

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I need to query Azure Table Storage multiple times from different tables then combine all results to output HTTP page.

Since the query is not related, means no particular order, so can I wrap all queries in one HTTP request to save my query time?

Or..

Can I send multiple Table Queries simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Azure Table Storage does not support this functionality. You would need to send each query  separately.

Comment: But yes, you can send multiple queries simultaneously (at the same time, not in the same HTTP request).

Comment: @smarx any sample on how can I sent multiple queries simultaneously?

Comment: @EricYin, it's a generic parallel processing scenario, not anything specific to Azure. The most efficient way would be using the Begin/EndQuerySegmented methods, but you could also use Tasks, the ThreadPool, or any other parallel approach.